# selecting measurements from specific points (crossectional) from longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a list of longitudinal data for a specific measurement. I would like to select only the last measurement per sample. For example, lets say I have measured the time it takes for a group of people to run a mile. I only want to select the measurement of their final time. example of data is below. Note that not all individuals have the same number of trials and some only have one.

```
         Name            Trial                Time 
        Jim                 0                  20:00
        Jim                 1                  21:00
        Jim                 2                  18:00
        Jim                 3                  18:25
        Mike                0                  17:00
        Mike                1                  16:30
        Sarah               0                  17:00
        Sarah               1                  13:00
        Tom                 0                  17:00
        Tom                 1                  16:58
        Tom                 2                  17:05
        Cindy               0                  14:00
        Cindy               1                  13:45
        Cindy               2                  13:25
        Cindy               3                  12:30
        Cindy               4                  12:30
        Cindy               5                  12:00
        Cindy               6                  10:00
        Jose                0                  14:00
        Juan                0                  17:00
        Juan                1                  17:30
        Juan                2                  20:00
```

What I am aiming for is below

```
     Name                  Trial          Time
      Jim                   3             18:25
      Mike                  1             16:30
      Sarah                 1             13:00
      Tom                   2             17:05
      Cindy                 6             10:00 
      Jose                  0             14:00
      Juan                  2             20:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dplyr to filter for each Name the maximum value of Trial

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
group_by(Name) %>%
filter(Trial == max(Trial)
```